# Error encrypting webm video with webm crypt

Tags: encryption, drm, webm

I'm trying to use the example [here](https://simpl.info/eme/clearkey/) for Clearkey encryption for videos. As per the steps mentioned [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Tl3i585GRXZXipBwPNyq4bP35XehayiegjfKVWC0T1U/) I was able to download and build the encryption tool `wemb_crypt` but When I try to encrypt the file with

```
webm_crypt -i input.webm -o input-enc_bear1_0123456789012345.webm -video true -audio true -video_options content_id=0123456789012345,base_file=bear1.key -audio_options content_id=0123456789012345,base_file=bear1.key
```

I get this error

> File: input.webm is not WebM file.Could not open WebM files.

Tried many different `webm` files with no luck.

Is there another way to encrypt clear key media with other tools? Any clue about the error above?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question to me.  Try SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ffmpeg and openssl to create an AES encrypted HLS stream - the ffmpeg documentation (http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Options-34) includes this example script:

```js
#!/bin/sh
BASE_URL=${1:-'.'}
openssl rand 16 > file.key
echo $BASE_URL/file.key > file.keyinfo
echo file.key >> file.keyinfo
echo $(openssl rand -hex 16) >> file.keyinfo
ffmpeg -f lavfi -re -i testsrc -c:v h264 -hls_flags delete_segments \
  -hls_key_info_file file.keyinfo out.m3u8
```

You can also use mp4Box (https://gpac.wp.imt.fr/mp4box/encryption/common-encryption/) to create basic clear DASH encryptions:

> MP4Box -crypt drm_file.xml movie.mp4 -out movie_encrypted.mp4

The drm info is included in the drm_file.xml and is explained at the link above.